# Tikz: positioning of circular framed photo in top right corner of CV, with control over the frame thickness and color, and x/y position

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, cv, tikz-node, anchor

My question is about photo positioning in Tikz.

I am writing a CV, in which I want to insert a photo on the top right corner, with a circular shape and a frame, thickness and color of which I can control.

Can someone please guide me how I can bring the photo to the north east corner with the control inputs of color and thickness of the frame and the x and y shifts from paper edges?

Thank you very much.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw[path picture={\node {\includegraphics[width=5.5cm]{example-image}}; } ] (0,0) circle [radius=2.5cm];
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: please have a look if the answer suits your requirements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though an excellent answer has been provided I was not satisfied since as a queried by the OP shift has not been used

First off the image path now has been defined as a node at the center of the bounding box by

```
path picture={%
             \node at (path picture bounding box.center){%
                            \includegraphics[width=2.4cm]{example-image}}}
```

This ensures that the image stays at center of the circle else it will default to one corner of the circle with only a corner of the image at the center of the circle

[image]

Second the options available are now shown after the first node is initialised

```
circle,
draw,%<----------since we are speaking in terms of node we need to execute draw
red,%<-----------color of the circle perimeter
line width=2pt,%<---------thickness of the circle border/perimeter 
fill=yellow,%<---------self-explanatory
minimum size=3cm,%<---represents the outer circle size/dia
text=white,%<--------------not used but in case something is to be written in or 
                           %around the node
```

[image]

Third the node has been aligned at `current page.center` and then shifted with the help of the `xshift` and `yshift` denoted by (x,y) which is added/subtracted to the center of the page

```
($(current page.center)+(3cm,0cm)$)
```

The node can be shifted anywhere with reference to the center of the page also and not compulsorily use `current page.north east` although that can also be done by simply changing

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node at ($(current page.north east)+(-3cm,-3cm)$)[%
             circle,
             draw,
             red,
             line width=2pt,
             fill=yellow,
             minimum size=3cm,
             text=white,
path picture={%
             \node at (path picture bounding box.center){%
                        \includegraphics[width=2.4cm]{example-image}
              };
           }]{};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Fourth scaling can be use for the inner image rather than width or height-- with scaling the aspect ratio is maintained however choice is yours

```
\node at (path picture bounding box.center){
        \includegraphics[scale=0.1]{example-image}
```

**MWE   with current page.center**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node at ($(current page.center)+(-3cm,0cm)$)[circle,draw,red,line 
 width=2pt,fill=yellow,minimum size=3cm,
text=white,
path picture={
    \node at (path picture bounding box.center){
        \includegraphics[width=2.4cm]{example-image}
    };
}]{};

\node at ($(current page.center)+(0cm,0cm)$)[circle,draw,red,line 
 width=2pt,fill=yellow,minimum size=2.4cm,
text=white,
path picture={
    \node at (path picture bounding box.center){
        \includegraphics[scale=0.1]{example-image}
    };
}]{};

\node at ($(current page.center)+(3cm,0cm)$)[circle,draw,red,line 
 width=2pt,fill=yellow,minimum size=3cm,
text=white,
path picture={
    \node at (path picture bounding box.center){
        \includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image}
    };
}]{};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Such a sound and complete answer. Thank you very much JS Bibra, your answer was a great help!

Comment: Dear js bibra, in case I wanted to have two frames around the circular picture with the same control options (for example the inner one with white and the outer one with red), how should I add the inner frame? Thanks again for the info.

Comment: may I suggest a new question to give other members an equal opportunity to answer -- regards

Answer (score 2):

You can define a scope and draw your circle after it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \begin{scope}
            \clip (current page text area.north east)
                circle (2) 
                node {\includegraphics[height=6cm]{example-image}};
        \end{scope}
            \draw [
                red,
                line width=2pt
                ] (current page text area.north east) circle (2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: north east]

Comment: Thank you very much Phil.